# In class design are nested classes always better?

Tags: sql-server, database-design, class-design

The following item will be maintained in a Microsoft SQL Server database and developed using EF code first:

[image]

Is it always better to define the classes nested, meaning as below (abbreviated definitions to keep it simple), letting the database do the work of maintaining the relationships:

```
Public Class Assembly
    Public Property assemblyID As Integer
    Public Property parts As New List(Of Part)
End Class

Public Class Part
    Public Property partID As Integer
    Public Property subitems As New List(Of Subitem)
End Class

Public Class Subitem
    Public Property subitemID As Integer
    Public Property components As New List(Of Component)
End Class

Public Class Component
    Public Property componentID As Integer
    Public Property elements As New List(Of Element)
End Class

Public Class Element
    Public Property elementID As Integer
    Public Property Name As New List(Of String)
End Class
```

Or is there ever ANY reason to keep the classes separate and do the manual work of maintaining the relationship between the records in each class, meaning as below:

```
Public Class Assembly
    Public Property assemblyID As Integer
    Public Property parts As New List(Of Integer) 'which would be partIDs
End Class

Public Class Part
    Public Property partID As Integer
    Public Property subitems As New List(Of Integer) 'which would be subitemIDs
End Class

Public Class Subitem
    Public Property subitemID As Integer
    Public Property components As New List(Of Integer) 'which would be componentIDs
End Class

Public Class Component
    Public Property componentID As Integer
    Public Property elements As New List(Of Integer) 'which would be elementIDs
End Class

Public Class Element
    Public Property elementID As Integer
    Public Property Name As New List(Of String)
End Class
```

I have always assumed we should design classes that are nested to follow the structure of the actual data. But since this is a deeper nesting I thought I would ask in case there are other design approaches I should consider.

In this particular case, all of the records are unique. I.E. even though I made this look like it's an assembled part, I was just trying to name each level distinctly. But in this case, any one of these layer items will never be used in a different assembly.

Comment: There is something else to consider (possibly).  Does your child collection ever have an attribute on the ~~relationship~~.  For example.  Employee can have many JobTitles.  However, the EmployeeStartedJobTitleOn (date) attribute is not an attribute of Employee, it is not an attribute of JobTitle (different employees could start on different dates).....it is an attribute of the ~~relationship (an employee started ~this JobTitle on this specific date).  If this is the case, you need to rework the EF some.  You have to have a EmployeeToJobTitle object that defines the StartDate.

Comment: The reason I bring this up, is that this "tactic" is also a way to a more composite way of defining the EF Poco's.  If "Element" could be a child-collection of Component (as shown) but it also is a child-collection of something .. say Part (now shown or inferred)...then you would use the "link" object to create relationships. #foodForThought but at the same time not painting yourself into a corner.  If EVER I think an entity might be "reused" OR I think they ~may be an attribute on the ~~relationship, I go ahead and setup these middle-man objects to future proof myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your structures have the same depth then your model may be the best. Else consider hierarchical structure. Something like this.

```
Public Class PartModel
   Public Property Id as Integer
   Public Property Name As String
   Public Property ParentId As Integer? ''Nullable(Of Integer)
   <ForeignKey("ParentId")>
   Public Property SubParts As List(Of PartModel) ''Note no **New** here. New will be in a Controller
End Class
```

Comment: Thx for confirming there can be times when not using a hierarchy is appropriate. And thx for showing a proper way to do that.  My 2nd example above was clearly not the right way to do it, but you got my intent and corrected it here.  I eventually decided to go with the 1st example above because it later became evident the layer/level definition could possibly diverge.